# RDATA for DNS PTR record

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm a bit confused about the relationship between `PTR` and `MX` records in DNS.

I understand the basic idea and need for these records:

Essentially, an `MX` record gives you the **hostname** of the SMTP server that delivers mail for a specified domain.  So if find the email address *`bob@example.com`*, I can lookup the `MX` record for `example.com` and get `mail.example.com` to know where to find the SMTP server.

Now, the `PTR` record comes into play if we *receive* an e-mail that purports to be from *`bob@example.com`*.  We can verify if the email is legitimate by doing a reverse DNS query on the IP address of the sender, and seeing if the DNS server gives us a `PTR` record that contains `mail.example.com`.

...but this is where I get confused.

When we verify that `bob@example.com` really is who he claims to be, is the DNS server supposed to send a `PTR` record that contains `mail.example.com` (i.e. the hostname of the SMTP server), or just `example.com` (i.e. the origin domain)?

In other words: should the zone file(s) contain records as follows:

```
example.com. MX IN 1 mail.example.com

...

IN  PTR   mail.example.com.
```

Or should the `PTR` record actually say:

```
IN  PTR   example.com.
```

Comment: Sorry... I'm a bit clueless here as to why I'm getting downvoted.  Explanation?

Comment: Probably because you have a flawed understanding of the relationship between an MX record and a PTR record.  Most implementations that perform dns checks simply verify that there is a corresponding A record for the hostname returned when looking up the PTR, that they match.  MX != 'delivers mail for', MX = 'receives mail for'.

Comment: Downvoter here! Nothing personal. I down voted and voted to close it for the reason: "Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) for further guidance." IMHO this topic has been answered thousands of times over in official documentation and should be learned like the rest of us learned it, from the source, not us repeating the source.

Answer (score 1):

`PTR` records are used to give names to IP addresses. In spam filtering, a sending server is frequently checked to see if its forward (A) and reverse (PTR) records match.

---

I think you may be confusing PTR with [`SPF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework), which can be used to validate if a sever should be sending mail for a domain. SPF is not without pitfalls, the most obvious being improper handling forwarding aliases. For a different solution to a close problem see [`DKIM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail).

Comment: `SPF`, not SFP.

Answer (score 1):

The `PTR` record in a reverse entry is expected to refer to the canonical hostname (fully qualified) associated with that IP address. It has no direct relation to smtp, `MX` records or email addresses.

`example.com` would be rather unorthodox (implying the hostname `example` placed directly into the domain `com`). Something like `zeus.example.com` would be a more typical example.

In the context of a mail server, you will probably want to ensure that the MTA is configured to identify itself by the same name that you have set up as the system hostname (which in turn would be what is expected in the `PTR`).